# How to edit fields in Microsoft Dynamics Portal

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-portals

We want to edit the text fields like "Alto", "Bajo" in the same web without enter to the "Edit" section.[image: example]

Comment: was my answer helpful?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for Editable grid, this is available in CRM UI but *unavailable* in Dynamics 365 Portals today. You can [watch this feature/idea](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/PowerApps-Ideas/Editable-Grid-for-the-CRM-Portal/idi-p/222841) for availability date.

Meantime, you can build your own form with editable layout using HTML/Liquid template.

AFAIK - No other easy readymade solution/configuration available (OOB), but there may be third party solutions out there.